# PHP Activerecord; pass in associative array as conditions

Tags: php, activerecord

I know in PHP Activerecord you can pass in condition arrays as:

```
// Data Structure
['a=? && b=?', 'foo', 'bar']

// Outputs:
// SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `a`="foo" && `b`="bar"
```

But I have an associative array generated in another part of the program I'd like to pass in as direct conditions. The columns can vary so I can't write the query string in advance, so can you pass in an associative array of key/value pairs to be used as conditions? I can't recall if I had issues with this. I don't see any documentation stating standard associative arrays are an allowable structure.

```
// Data Structure
['a' =>'foo', 'b' => 'bar']

// Outputs:
// SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `a`="foo" && `b`="bar"
```

And lastly, can conditions be mixed between the two methods? I also have conditions which I want to pass in along with the key/value pairs.

```
// Data Structure
['(a=? || b=?)', 'foo', 'bar', 'c' => 'baz']

// Outputs:
// SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`a`="foo" || `b`="bar") && `c`="baz"
```

Is this possible in PHP Activerecord, and also - is it a safe/reliable operation?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this to ensure consistent behaviour. Syntax is:

```
mixedConditions($associativeArray, $statement = '', ...$parameters);
```

Used like...

```
mixedConditions(['a'=>'foo', 'b'=>'bar'],'`c`=? && `d`=?','baz','qux');
```

Which would output an array containing

```
Array
(
    [0] => `a` = ? && `b` = ? && `c`=? && `d`=?
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
    [3] => baz
    [4] => qux
)
```

The function: (untested)

```
function mixedConditions ($assoc, $statement = '')
{
    $conditions = [];
    $statementConditions = array_slice(func_get_args(),2);

    foreach ($assoc as $key => $value)
        if (is_array($value))
            $conditions[] = '`'.preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9\-_]#i','',$key).'` IN (?)';
        else
            $conditions[] = '`'.preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9\-_]#i','',$key).'` = ?';


    if (!empty($statement))
        return array_merge([implode(' && ', array_merge($conditions, [$statement]))], array_values($assoc), $statementConditions);
    else
        return array_merge([implode(' && ', $conditions)], array_values($assoc));
}
```

Note: The function will strip exotic characters from parameter names.

If Activerecord has a better or internal method of doing this, let me know and I'll pick your answer still.